# Positioning of a DIV

Tags: html

I am trying to fit a normal web player into a wordpress post.  My site is self hosted. The problem is with the positioning of a DIV (not really an issue with wordpress).

Here is the page that I am working on:
http://grayradio.com/mishkin-hits/

The music player was supposed to come at the post area but it is going all the way down below the footer.

I am inserting all the necessary code within the post's main container but for some reason the div class 'ttw-music-player' goes out of this container div.

I tested by putting a paragraph text inside the post's main container at the same time keeping the div class 'ttw-music-player'.  The paragraph text appeared properly but the player div went out.

I have access to change my code and that of the player's but I am not sure where to start.  Please help.  Thank you.

Comment: I was able to figure out the problem myself.  Thanks for checking.

Comment: I was using 'body' tag to position the player in one of the JS files.  When i changed it to a specific DIV, it worked.  Not sure if it is a wordpress specific thing!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using 'body' tag to position the player in one of the JS files. When i changed it to a specific DIV, it worked. Not sure if it is a wordpress specific thing!!